# NESBox to VirtualBoy Advance Save File Conversion

Tags: emulation, game-boy-advance

I have used the NESBox Emulator with my dumped Pokemon Emerald .gba and I have used the "Save state" button. I have played a lot on NESBox and now that I would like to use VirtualBoy Advance I cannot load NESBox save file (.save) that I saved my data to, because it errors with "Unrecognized Gave Version".

Does anyone here know how to convert NESBox state files (.save) to VirtualBoy Advance-compatible Save files (.sgm)?

Comment: Have you tried saving the game normally and migrating the regular save file instead of the save state?

Comment: @Nolonar NESBox has only a "save state" button. You can view it here: http://nesbox.com/emulator

Comment: Yes, but Pokémon has a "Save" option. Have you tried using *that*?

Comment: @Nolonar Yes, but it doesn't save to a file. At least it displays to me no file save dialog... I appreciate your help a lot!!!

Comment: @Jason Most emulators just have a save or battery folder that they put all the game save info on.

Comment: @Powerlord I have looked inside all Macromedia folders and there is no file regarding NESBox...

Comment: Are you using the Flash version on the NESBox website?

Comment: @Mego Yes, I am.

Comment: So, there is now way I can port my data to VirtualBoy Advance? Oh, no...

Comment: Isn't there anyone here who can help me convert the state file formats? Please, I need to have my game file...

Comment: Requesting help again...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, neither the Flash version on the NESBox website nor the Microsoft Store app have saving functionality aside from the save state feature. There is no way to convert a NESBox save state to a save state for any other emulator, because the format and data is specific to the emulator.

Comment: That's very bad news for me: I have played a lot and now I am going to just have to start again...